# Internal error when I run Ubuntu Software in 16.4

Tags: command-line

In Ubuntu 16.4, Ubuntu Software used to work fine now it fails giving a system error I have attached a screenshot

[image: Screen when I try to run Ubuntu software]I have installed the older Software Center which works fine. But I would still like to get Ubuntu software working. How? Would removing and reinstalling help? If so, what commands

Answer (score 1):

I ran sudo apt-get upgrade gnome-software and Ubuntu Software appears to be working.